# Appium - automating multiple Android apps in one session

Tags: mobile, automation, appium, ui-automation, appium-android

According to Appium [documentation](https://github.com/appium/appium/blob/master/docs/en/about-appium/platform-support.md), it supports automating multiple Android apps in one session.

I've looked for any example online but had no success.
Can someone please share an example?

I'm testing an Android app and coding in Java.

Comment: Have you tried closing the app and initializing the driver again?

Answer (score 1):

1) You need 2 appium running with each different ports

```
baseUrl_1 = "http://appiumAddress:4726/wd/hub"
baseUrl_2 = "http:/appiumAddress:4725/wd/hub"
```

2) You need to 2 different instances of android emulator. Make sure you just run different emulators (what I mean it can be the same version everything but the 2nd one change the name). Apparently appium was getting confuse if you run it with the same.

3) You need to set the capabilities for each emulator:

```
    caps1 = {
    platformName:"ANDROID",
    platformVersion: "4.4",
    deviceName: "emulator-5554",
    app: "app1Path.apk",
           browserName: "",
     }

    caps2 = {
    platformName:"ANDROID",
    platformVersion: "4.4",
    deviceName: "emulator-5556",
    app: "app2Path.apk",
    browserName: ""
    }
```

4) Write session for each app in a try catch separately

**Driver-1**

```
 try {
                     driver_1 = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(baseUrl_1), caps1);

                 } catch (Exception e) {

                        e.printStackTrace();
                    }
```

**Driver-2**

```
try {
                 driver_2 = new AndroidDriver<MobileElement>(new URL(baseUrl_2), caps2);

             } catch (Exception e) {

                    e.printStackTrace();
                }
```

when you run your test 1 app is going to display on 1 emulator and the 2nd app with the 2nd emulator. That's it everything else depends on your script or whatever environment you are using.

I hope this helps

For more information check this.

https://discuss.appium.io/t/how-to-use-to-2-apps-sequentially-in-one-session/1806/6

Answer (score 0):

I think Appium Studio could provide a better solution to this.
In Appium Studio, following is the code to launch 2 applications with the same driver instance.

```
client.launch(String activityURL1, boolean instrument, boolean stopIfRunning);
//work on app 1
client.applicationClose(String activityURL1);
client.launch(String activityURL2, boolean instrument, boolean stopIfRunning);
//work on app 2
client.applicationClose(String activityURL2);
```

activityURL - activity url of the application to be launched. You can get this on uploading the apk file to their studio.

You can work on the apps sequentially or you can even work on app1, push it to background, work on app2, bring app1 to foreground and work with it.

You can also look at this documentation for [launch](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TD/SeeTestAutomation+-+Launch) and [close](https://docs.experitest.com/display/public/TD/SeeTestAutomation-+ApplicationClose) commands.